# prompt-read and autocomplete conflict in slime

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, slime

I have auto-complete-mode turned on in the slime repl (which is great), but if I enter `(prompt-read "What? ")` I get this error:

```
; pipelined request... (swank:simple-completions "ye" (quote "COMMON-LISP-USER"))
```

Turning off autocomplete mode fixes this, but I rather be able to leave it on. Is there any way to work around this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I am encountering this problem and can't fix it easily.